# Html file writing from a for loop's output

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a Python WebScraper like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get('http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm?cat=G&utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email')

html_page = wd.page_source
wd.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
table = soup.find("table", attrs = {"id":"topGainers"})
print "success"
#print table
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    #print cols
    #break
    some = [cols[0], cols[5], cols[6], cols[9]]
    #print some
    #break
    for td in some:
        
        if td.find(text = True):
                text = ''.join(td.find(text = True))
                print text + "|"
            
        else:
                continue
```

Now I Want my output (text) to be in a html file in a table format.How could i do that??

Comment: In your last if block add to a string you declare before your for loop.  Start the string off as "<table><tr><td>heading1</td><td>heading2</td></tr>" etc and just build it up in the bottom if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Okay first if you want the table to have HEADERS above each column you should save the heading names in a list like so...
listofheaders=['header1','header2','header3']

#for each row in the table save the data included in the row in a list of lists something like this:
listofrows=[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]

#now create a string with the following:
htmlstuff='<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\ntable,th,td\n{\nborder:1px solid black;\nborder-collapse:collapse;\n}\nth,td\n{\npadding:5px;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<table style="width:300px">\n<tr>\n  '

#now you would add the COLUMN HEADERS to the list...
for header in listofheaders:
    htmlstuff=htmlstuff+'<th>'+str(header)+'</th>\n'

#then you can populate the table row by row...
for row in listofrows:
    htmlstuff+='  <tr>\n'
    for item in row:
        htmlstuff=htmlstuff+'    <td>'+str(item)+'</td>\n'
    htmlstuff+='  </tr>\n'

#finish off the html coding...
htmlstuff+='</table>\n</body>\n\n</html>'

#now create the html page and write the data...
f=open('webpage.html','w')
f.write(htmlstuff)
f.close()
```

You can even use webbrowser to automatically open the page for you.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('webpage.html')
```